# How to deploy classic asp website?

Tags: deployment, iis-7, asp-classic, setup-deployment

I would like to know how to deploy or what are the steps that are involved to deploy a classic asp website in IIS 6/7

Can we create an installer for the existing project?

Comment: ummm, find a way back machine? jk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the files to the virtual folder. If you have any depending dll's or exe's make sure to install them too.

As you said you may have to create an installer that will do this works to you. There is a lot of installers out there, like [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) and Windows Installer.

Comment: Thanks mendy, is there anything that i need to do to make run that application. Like, do i need to activate anything on my machine to work. another question is Can we create an installer for the existing project? i want my application to work on any systems.
what is the best practive in deploying classic asp website?
Please let me know this. What does xCopy deployment do?

Comment: Nimesh, are you making this harder than it has to be? Classic ASP is really simple. It's almost like a pure HTML web site. There is no installation, just files. You can drag and drop the .asp files in windows; xcopy is just a (good) command line utility for doing the same thing. As others said, if you're using custom DLLs you have to register them, but for simple sites this isn't commonly needed. If you try the steps Kyle listed, what is the behavior you get?

Comment: Yeah but i am checking all the possible ways. I could copy all the files and placed into the virtual dirctory and the web site is up and running. But my intention is to give an installer to the client, where they can install, instead of creating the Virtual Directory and copy the files manually...

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using Web Deploy http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy, it can deploy your ASP applications, setup the IIS application and other settings (like APplication Pool, etc), and even include COM objects, Registry keys and more.
Even better you can parameterize content like Connection Strings, Title, settings, so that at install time you can pass those paramters either through the command line or the User Interface. 
It can deploy between IIS 6 and IIS 7 and even help you compare existing deployed versions with packaged versions (zip files), or other servers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure a [virtual directory has been set up](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138) in IIS.
2. Copy all files into the virtual directory
3. If applicable, [register required DLLs with regsvr32.exe](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspDLL.php)
4. Run.

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: I see you want to make an installer for the application. Have a [look here for a guide](http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2007/12/12/creating-windows-installers-web-applications-and-virtual-directories.aspx) on how to do it. To my knowledge there isn't anything that is "plug and play" for installing your project; you will have to make it.

Answer (score 1):

If its just ASP and you have no DLL's or COM Components then you would just have to copy all the files to a Virtual Directory under approot or wwwroot.  XCopy copies all directories, subdirectories and files.  As for an installer, you wouldn't really need it but it would be useful if you make one that sets up the virtual directory, copies the files and configures any host headers if needed.

Comment: Could u please give me some links where i can make some installer??

Comment: Finally i got the idea how to create setup for classic asp.
Create new website in Visual Studio, then delete all the files in that folder. Say default.aspx,aspx.cs and we.config.
Then right click on the solution explorer, web site and click on add existing item. select the asp files in the project and after that add websetup project, rest of the steps is same as creating setup for asp.net application.