# How to make a classic ASP application work

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp application that is very old an d I want to make it work, any help would be appreciated because I don't have much idea on how to do so

Comment: post the question with details about your application.

Comment: That's what I did. I have a classic asp application (a folder with a bunch of asp files) that I want to execute it but I have no idea how

Comment: This is a not suitable question for SO.

Comment: how is asking for help not suitable ?

Comment: If you just want to know how to run classic asp on whatever version of IIS you use then Google is your friend.  Questions on here need to be much more specific and ideally accompanied with examples of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this threads on stack over flow -
[How to guide for getting a classic asp application working under IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637326/how-to-guide-for-getting-a-classic-asp-application-working-under-iis-7-0?rq=1)

[How to deploy classic asp website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316256/how-to-deploy-classic-asp-website)

OR

check this steps also -

**To use the UI on Windows Server 2008 or Server 2008 R2**

Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Server Manager.

In Roles Summary, click Add Roles.

Use the Add Roles Wizard to add the Web Server (IIS) role.

For detailed instructions about how to install a default IIS 7 Web server, see Deploying a Static Content Server (IIS 7).

On the Select Role Services page, note the preselected role services that are installed by default, and then select the following additional role services:
        ASP

```
    Request Filtering

    ISAPI Extensions
```

On the Summary of Features to Install page, confirm your selections, and then click Install.

On the Installation Results page, confirm that your installation of the Web Server (IIS) role and required role services completed successfully, and then click Close.

To verify that IIS installed successfully, type the following into a Web browser:

```
http://localhost
```

You should see the default IIS 7 Welcome page.

**To use the UI on Windows Vista or Windows 7**

Click Start, and then click Control Panel.

In Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.

In the Windows Features dialog box, click Internet Information Services to install the default features, and then select the following additional features:
        ASP

```
    Request Filtering

    ISAPI Extensions
```

Click OK to close the Windows Features dialog box.

To verify that IIS installed successfully, type the following into a Web browser:

```
http://localhost
```

You should see the default IIS Welcome page.

Comment: thank you, i followed the steps, created a pool where i put my ASP website in it. But then how can I open it on the browser ?

Comment: for example if your file is 'my_first-asp-page.asp' and save the file to a directory accessible through your web server (this will usually be, 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot', on IIS or PWS with a default install).

To display the page open your web browser and type 'http://my_computer/my_first-asp-page.asp', where 'my_computer' is replaced with the name of the computer

Comment: Thanks Anita, you've been a great help. I've also followed these two links in order to make it work 

http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-install-iis-7-and-setup-asp-in-windows-7/

and

http://justinchronicles.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/setting-up-classic-asp-websites-on-iis-7-5-with-visual-studio-2010/